# gdb jumping due to c++ destructor

Tags: c++, gdb, destructor

I have function like:

```cpp
      int ConfigConvTensors(LayerType layer_type, bool batch_processing = false) {
        /* Construct the convolution problem */
2=>     std::list<std::string> input_coupled_vars;
        std::list<std::string> weight_coupled_vars;
        std::list<std::string> output_coupled_vars;
        ...
1=>     someOtherFunction();
        return 1;
3=>   }
```

While debugging using gdb, the cursor moves from `1->2->3`. I think that's due to destructors. But is there a way to tell gdb: "don't care about destructor debugging and just do `1->3`"?

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49951 seems related but I am facing this issue with `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2` .

The command line I used:

```sh
g++ -o cost-model/src/BASE_base-objects.o -c -O0 -g -std=c++17 $BunchOfLinkerAndIncludeFlags cost-model/src/BASE_base-objects.cpp
```

Comment: It's not yet time for local variables to be destroyed unless you're letting the optimizer at the code. Optimized code is a lot harder to debug because the output looks like the code went through a blender. I recommend adding the compiler command line to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the generated code, it could provide some insight into what's happening, could be optimization of some sort.
https://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/disassemble